# MatLab algorithm for Jacobi method

Tags: matlab, sum

I have some difficulties in converting a pseudocode into a MatLab algorithm.  Specifically, there is one part I don't quite know how to do.  I will write the pseudocode up to the point where I am uncertain:

```
 input n, (a_{ij}), (b_i), (x_i), M
    for k = 1 to M do
       for i = 1 to n do

           u_i = (b_i - sum[(from j = 1, (j ≠ i), to n) a_{ij} * x_j]) / a_{ii}
       end do
```

The difficulty I have is when I have to write the sum-part.  What I can't figure out is how to write the algorithm so that terms where j ≠ i are not included.  So far I have written:

```
function [k,x] = jacobimethod(A,b,M)
n = length(A);
u = zeros(1,n);
x = zeros(1,n);
for k = 1:M
    for i = 1:n
        u(i) = (b(i) - (A(i
```

And this is where I get stuck.  So far, all my algorithms have involved sums where all terms should be included, even those where j = i.  In this case, the sum term will simply be:

```
A(i,1:n)*x(1:n)'
```

But how can I modify this so that `A(i,i)` is not included?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an explicit index array and remove the index you don't need

```
% inside of the loop
idx = 1:n;
idx(i) = [];
u(i) = (b(i)-sum(A(i,idx).*x(idx)))/A(i,i);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you HAVE provided code, thus made an effort... I'll point out a better approach. When you use MATLAB, try to use the capabilities of the language. Don't pretend you are still using a lower level language. Thus, we can write a jacobi iteration as

```
X_(n+1) = inv(D)*(b - R*X_n)
```

Where D is a diagonal matrix that contains the diagonal of A, and R is the matrix of off-diagonal elements of A, so there are zeros on the diagonal. How can we do this in MATLAB?

First, build D and R in a simple way.

```
D = diag(diag(A));
R = A - D;
```

Now, we should recognize that computing the inverse of a diagonal matrix is silly. Better is to compute the inverse of each elements on the diagonal.

```
Dinv = diag(1./diag(A));
```

So, now we can write a single Jacobi iterate, as

```
X = Dinv*(b - R*X);
```

See that NO nested loops were needed. We don't bother to index into these matrices at all. Now wrap it all up in a MATLAB function. Be friendly, check for problems, and use comments liberally.

==================================================

```
function [X,residuals,iter] = JacobiMethod(A,b)
% solves a linear system using Jacobi iterations
%
% The presumption is that A is nxn square and has no zeros on the diagonal
% also, A must be diagonally dominant for convergence.
% b must be an nx1 vector.

n = size(A,1);
if n ~= size(A,2)
  error('JACOBIMETHOD:Anotsquare','A must be n by n square matrix')
end
if ~isequal(size(b),[n 1])
  error('JACOBIMETHOD:incompatibleshapes','b must be an n by 1 vector')
end

% get the diagonal elements
D = diag(A);
% test that none are zero
if any(D) == 0
  error('JACOBIMETHOD:zerodiagonal', ...
    'The sky is falling! There are zeros on the diagonal')
end

% since none are zero, we can compute the inverse of D.
% even better is to make Dinv a sparse diagonal matrix,
% for better speed in the multiplies.
Dinv = sparse(diag(1./D));
R = A - diag(D);

% starting values. I'm not being very creative here, but
% using the vector b as a starting value seems reasonable.
X = b;
err = inf;
tol = 100*eps(norm(b));
iter = 0; % count iterations
while err > tol
  iter = iter + 1;
  Xold = X;

  % the guts of the iteration
  X = Dinv*(b - R*X);

  % this is not really an error, but a change per iteration.
  % when that is stable, we choose to terminate.
  err = norm(X - Xold);
end

% compute residuals
residuals = b - A*X;
```

==================================================

Lets see how this works.

```
A = rand(5) + 4*eye(5);
b = rand(5,1);
[X,res,iter] = JacobiMethod(A,b)

X =
      0.12869
   -0.0021942
      0.10779
      0.11791
      0.11785

res =
   5.7732e-15
   1.6653e-14
   1.5654e-14
   1.6542e-14
    1.843e-14

iter =
    39
```

Did it converge to the solution we get from backslash?

```
A\b
ans =
      0.12869
   -0.0021942
      0.10779
      0.11791
      0.11785
```

It looks good to me. Better code might check for diagonal dominance to try to predict when the code will fail. I might have chosen a more intelligent tolerance on the solution, or a better starting value for X. And finally, I would want to provide more complete help, with references.

What you want to see are the general characteristics of good code.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!  This is really helpful.  I'm still a MatLab novice taking my first numerical analysis course.  I only have some experience with Java from before, so my mind is still, as you put it, more wrapped around lower level language.  Further, all the algorithms in the book, and the class homework, encourage us to approach the problems like this.  I guess the point is that we should understand the nuts and bolts, before we move on to more elegant features as you outline here.  Still, I'm very grateful for this!  And I understand all your steps :)

Comment: (Don't expect me to do this often.) But the point is to emulate the code I offered. Use error checks. Have lots of comments that explain what you are doing. Return that information which will be useful. And do it all in an efficient way so you avoid deeply nested loops where matrix operations will suffice.

Comment: Yes, I don't expect this kind of help often :).  I agree with you on the error checks and comments, and I always include these on assignments that need to be handed in, or when I am working on more elaborate coding.  However, when I am just practicing on converting simple pseudoalgorithms from my textbook into MatLab, only intended for private use, I take a few short-cuts.  I will definitely take your advice and tips, though!  Again, I really appreciate your efforts.